# Ajax wrapper replacement on a field widget form

Tags: 7, ajax, entities

I'm having ajax-related problem while building my custom compound field. The problem is similar to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31870/how-to-create-an-ajax-field-widget).

The field widget consist of a `textfield` (autocomplete) and `markup`. They are defined like this in the `hook_field_widget_form`:

```
   $element['symbol'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Phrase'),
      '#required' => $delta == 0 && $instance['required'],
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['symbol']) ? $items[$delta]['symbol'] : NULL,
      '#size' => $settings['size'],
      '#element_validate' => array('_ghs_field_validate'),
      '#autocomplete_path' => 'admin/ghs/get',
    );
    $element['description'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<span class="ghs-desc-' . $delta . '">[no phrase selected]</span>',
    );
```

Of course this is accompanied by `hook_menu()` for the autocomplete path and a callback function. But this is working fine, so there's no need to paste the code.

The problem I'm having is that I want a front-end callback that would do wrapper replacement of the `$element['description']`.

I tried to do that following the Ajax Example, replacing `#autocomplete_path` with:

```
'#ajax' => array(
  'callback' => 'ajax_example_simplest_callback',
  'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
),
```

This is the way that commerce guys used for commerce_line_item ([snippet](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_field_widget_form/7)) but I must be doing something wrong when trying to mimic their code.

A plus of the `#autocomplete_path` way is that it provides a visual signal (a throbber) that it is a lookup field. This may be important for site editors later.

To cut a long story short - is the `<span>` replacement doable using the `#autocomplete_path` property of the element? Is there any extra js code needed to do that?

Comment: You can use next events http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers and change div element at ajax completing from textfield...