# AJAX callback fails using form_alter on two fields

Tags: forms, ajax

I have content type with two text fields field1, field2
so i'm using hook_form_alter() to alter my form and i'm added for the first field

- ## autocomplete_path path
- ## ajax callback and wrraper

and for the second field i'm added

- ## prefix : with id ind the wrraper of first field
- ## suffix

I want to add a AJAX callback to check the value of a first field and added this value to check a value of second with autocomplete .

The code:

```
function ajax_callback($form,$form_state) {         
        return $form['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value'];
    }

    function newsletter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        //dpm($form['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value']);
        if ($form_id == 'newsletter_node_form') {
            $form['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'admin/get_path/autocomplete_field1';
            $form['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value']['#ajax'] = array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_callback',
                'wrapper' => 'autocomplete_id',
            );

            $form['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
            $form['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#prefix'] = '<div id="autocomplete_id">';
            $form['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

            if (isset($form_state['values']['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value'])) {
                ['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
                ['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#autocomplete_path'] = "admin/publicite/autocomplete_field2/{$form_state['values']['field_annonceur']['und']['0']['value']}";
            }           
            return $form;
        }
    }

autocomplete_field1($value_field1){};
autocomplete_field2($value_field1,$value_field2){};
```

but i get the same field  when i select a first field , the second field is hidden !!

before input on field 1

[image]

after input on field 1

[image]

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value']['#disabled']` - what is this? `['field_campagne']['und']['0']*` is the correct way I think. `* - ['#disabled'], ['#prefix']` and so on.. But not `[n]['value'][*]`

Comment: i'm displayed the form dpm($form) and the [value] works fine the problem in the ajax callback .

Comment: I don't thinks that you need add an `#ajax` attribute to the value of field. Add it to the field itself instead.

Comment: i'm added the #ajax into the field but no ajax fired :(

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31870/how-to-create-an-ajax-field-widget - look at Clive's answer.

Comment: it works fine without node form alter in hook_form()

Comment: i'm found the solution in the ajax callaback return just 
$form['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value'] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to return the target field in the ajax callback
so the code is :

```
function ajax_callback($form,$form_state) {         
        return $form['field_campagne']['und']['0']['value'];
    }
```